# Problematic webGL support in electron

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webgl, electron

I have big problem with using webGL by webview in the electron application that run on mac osx. 
I need some extra dependencies like ES6,React,LESS so i basically include in the devDependencies newest "electron-prebuilt-compile" version. Unfortunately in that case webview with webGL is not runnning properly and electron prompt me such message:
[Electron error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9ls0.png)

> An error occured running the Unity content on this page. See your browser's JavaScript console for more info. the error was: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Then, if i change devDependency into "electron", webGL support is working properly. Unfortunately EcmaScript methods like import/export and whole React dependcies are not working. I tried to add those dependencies by hand in the "dependencies" section (babel, sass, react) but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use webpack to transpile your React app and use loadURL to read the generated bundle. You can even use a localhost address on electron to use react-hot-loader with webpack-dev server (in dev mod).

A sample webpack.config.js would be:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ProgressBarPlugin = require('progress-bar-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

const commomPlugins = [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.html' // this is your html file
  }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].bundle.css'),
  new ProgressBarPlugin()
]

const devPlugins = [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
]

const optimizePlugins = [
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: ['vendor']
  })
]
// run optimizations only on production
let plugins = commomPlugins
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'production':
    plugins = plugins.concat(optimizePlugins)
    break
  default:
    plugins = plugins.concat(devPlugins)
    break
}

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // react subfolder
  entry: {
    app: [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      './index'
    ],
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'), // output code to www folder under src
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins,
  externals: {
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true
  }
}
```

And the electron file:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let toLoad = process.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'www', 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  })
  : 'http://localhost:8080/'

let win

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL(toLoad)

  if (process.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    win.webContents.openDevTools()
  }

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}
// ...
```

And finally your package.json (for dev you should exec `npm build-dev` and `npm electron-dev` in separated terminals, for production exec `npm run build` and `npm run start` after it):

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build-dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server",
    "electron-dev": "NODE_ENV=development electron .",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "electron": "^1.6.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^1.10.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.7",
    "webpack": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!